# How to understand ${var:-world}

Tags: linux, shell

```
# echo ${var}

# echo ${var:-world}
world
# var='hello'
# echo ${var}
hello
# echo ${var:-world}
hello
```

Could you explain why the second `echo ${var:-world}` output `hello` other than `world`?

By the way, what's the topic called in English? I searched cut string, sub string...
Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing these experiments as root?  Or are you using '# ' as the default prompt for a non-root user?  Either way, stop doing that.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes, I login as root. Why can not using "#"? Is it stackoverflow rule, or some other concerns for using linux?

Comment: The convention is that '#' as the leading character in the prompt indicates a root login.  it is nearly universally acknowledged that running an interactive shell as root is bad practice, and since the introduction of `sudo` rarely necessary.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yeah, universal but for me :). Anyway, thanks! I'll try to be more professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${name:-alternate}` is a *parameter expansion with a default value*.  From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> `${parameter:-word}`
>
> Use Default Values. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

The first `${var:-world}` printed `world` because `$var` was unset.  The second printed `hello` because you had set `$var=hello`, so `$var` was no longer unset.  Therefore, the default (`world`) was ignored.

More info is at the [bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value).